# Laravel get all related models for multiple models

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, entity-relationship

I have a users table and a groups table. 
I have set up a many to many users/groups relations. 
When I run

```
$users = User::where("id",'=',6)->first()->groups;
```

,I get the right group.

But I will have cases where my queries will take in an array of users. 
How do I get all the groups of all those users using laravel relationships ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

eMAD's suggestion does not work because Laravel only allows relationship functions to be execute on objects and not array of objects. What you want harvey is a concept called eager loading.

```
$users = User::whereIn('id', [6, 7, 8])->with('groups')->get();
```

By using this code, you will be able to access `$user->groups->someInfo` in your code. Happy coding

Comment: could you tell me in english ,what that with function is doing ? 
and does it still utilise the relationship i defined in my groups and users models ?

Comment: i have another question related to this. 
I also have a table called ACTION, with a many to to relationship to a table called VOTE . now, VOTE table has a one to many relationship on a table called sub items. 
Is it possible to get all the vote rows, along with their sub item rows , for a set of given actions ?

Comment: When you use User::findOrFail(1), it only loads the User model and not other models that are related to it. To load in all the models along with it, you can use the with('parameter') method to load in relevant Models. The parameter of the with function takes in the name of the function declared in the model class just as you guessed. Actually you can chain to load in even distant relevant models. ex: User::with('groups.Members'). this then allows you to call $user->groups->members, assuming that the Group model was relatable to the Member Model. Hope you got it

Comment: see I anticipated such question ;)